# Is it possible for the RewriteEngine (.htaccess) not to seemingly remove the headers?

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess

I have a small ajax running with php on a server. That directory has a .htaccess which has the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exampleDomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.exampleDomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This part is meant to redirect the http requests to https. However, I call the ajax from outside the domain, so I added:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

This is meant to tell the browser to ignore CORS policy.

I am using jQuery to make a get request (I don't think jQuery is the problem), and it only works with https. If I make a request to http://exampleDomain.com, the server will **not** respond with the access-control-allow-origin header. On the contrary, http://www.exampleDomain.com, https://www.exampleDomain.com and https://exampleDomain.com all respond with the header. I want to keep the HTTP upgrade functionality, whether that is using .htaccess or not, without it interfering with the headers sent back.

This is the code that makes the failed request:

```
$.get("http://exampleDomain.com/path/to/file.php", {}, res => console.log(res))
```

Ideally, I would just change the request to https, but the code is already in production.

I am using Apache2 and PHP7.

Comment: So it sounds like your main app is running in HTTPS and your AJAX operation is running in an unencrypted connection. I think that would invalidate your HTTPS connection, and browsers would generally show a broken HTTPS state as if a image was being loaded in plaintext.

Comment: You say that ideally you would just change the request to HTTPS. Can you elucidate why you can't do that? It seems like the simplest fix here. The `[R]` flag means that the unencrypted request has to come into the web server first, at which point I would expect the browser to invalidate the perfect HTTPS status.

Comment: Did you place the HEADER directive before or after the rewrite? (Not sure it matters, but if you currently placed it after, I would give changing the order a try at least. Figuring out in which order this stuff gets applied, when several different modules are involved, isn’t always easy.)

Comment: I tried changing the order but it doesn't seem to work, unfortunately. I'm not sure what the flags mean, but maybe by changing that it could work?